# Violinplots in seaborn not showing mean, percentiles nor sticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

When I try to replicate the example [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb), my violin plots (with my data) don't show the median and  median, along with the 25th and 75th percentile, but the original example does.

It also seems to ignore the argument `"sticks"` to it.

Here is what I tried:

```
sns.violinplot(df, "stick", color="pastel")
```

and here is what I get:

[image]

while the original looks like the following (for `sns.violinplot(df, color="pastel")`):

[image]

### NOTE:

This problem does **not** affect boxplots.

Here is a minimal example which results in (very similar) shapes:

```
> df

                                A               B
0RS0NrQDHHx                   NaN        19.727869
0RS232Ak80k                   NaN        32.552973
0RSECe1NRShE                  NaN        44.369213
0RSHVQNT16d                   NaN        11.306910
0RSO4JcoLeb                   NaN        -7.935776
0RSOrrpKlRu                   NaN        39.489909
0RSVIHDWBR1                   NaN        52.830051
0RSWe5CE1Hk                   NaN        26.913323
0RSXhLG3Kp8             -1.921543              NaN
0RSc8uRSessd             27.028029             NaN
0RScRSZoDX72             12.713600             NaN
0RSdwNiizS0             28.859158              NaN
0RSeWHWRSww3             12.537717             NaN
0RSrs6jjCsM              5.135179              NaN
0RStNwVhvO1            -55.566641              NaN
0RStQI2VH5A            -15.119272              NaN
0RStWRWmH8V             -2.369918              NaN
0RSukeajMJy             -0.904298              NaN
0RSvJezMyrx             -1.105769              NaN
0RSx5WRStDjG             0.899420              NaN
```

Comment: please post a minimal working example that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try `sns.violinplot(df, inner="stick", color="pastel")`. The second positional argument is a grouping variable. (Although, `inner="stick"` shows each observation. If you want the 25, 50, and 75th percentiles, do `inner="box"`).

Also to handle a relatively sparse dataframe with lots of NAs, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 5), columns=list("ABCDE"))
for i, c in zip(range(5, 10), df.columns):
    df.loc[i, c] = np.nan
```

you could do

```
plot_vals = [v.dropna() for k, v in foo.iteritems()] 
sns.violinplot(plot_vals, names=df.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks - But didn't fix it. I wonder if the problem is the `NaNs`? (even though the box plot can figure out the median, and percentiles)

Comment: That might be the problem, I don't think the percentile computation is nan-safe. Just plot with `df.dropna()`.

Comment: Thanks, although `df.dropna()` in my case will simply reduce to an empty dataframe. Any suggestions?